# Appending DOM elements after page reload on ajax success call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, reload

```
        $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : requesturl,
        data        : data,
        dataType    : 'json',
        success     : function(data) {
            location.reload();
            $('#status').append(
                                // append something here!!
            );
            $('#loader').hide();                
        }
    });
```

I'm having some issues forcing the page to reload first and then appending my elements. I need this functionality to occur since the page will initialize again on reload and wipe out the elements I'm trying to append.

Comment: You can't do this. You would have to append a hash or query string variable, then check for the existence of it.

Comment: This sounds contradictive. Why are you using AJAX to fetch data when you need to reload the page anyway? Or why is it that you want to reload the page?

Comment: When the page reloads, the JavaScript code *stops executing*.  This is because browsers don't continue to execute code for pages that the user visited in the past.  Either append the content via AJAX *without reloading the page* or modify the content server-side during the page re-load before returning it to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `location.reload()` it's too late. The scripts won't continue to run after the page has reloaded.

It sounds like you may need to rethink your general approach here. A common approach would be to not use AJAX at all (since you plan to reload the page anyway), or have the server render the page in the desired new state, including whatever you were going to append to it.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use location.reload()  here Instead use $('.yoursubClass').remove() and then call append method.

```
 $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : requesturl,
        data        : data,
        dataType    : 'json',
        success     : function(data) {
            $('#status').find('yourRemovableElements').remove(); //modify yourRemovableElements accordingly 
            $('#status').append(
                                // append something here!!
            );
            $('#loader').hide();                
        }
    });
```

Comment: This should do the trick. Vote up for this, Thanks. My approach is a bit off.